# Html css space between divs using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row using bootstrap and I want to add space between each section except the first and last child. However, my code is causing the row to overflow.

HTML:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 section">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 section">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 section">
                    hello
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.section{
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.section:first-of-type{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: green;

}

.section:last-of-type{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: blue;

}
```

Output:

```
Hello         Hello
Hello
```

Comment: Where is the parent div `row`'s width defined?

Comment: Do you need the columns to be 4? why not make them 3 and simply add `margin-left` to all 3 of them?

Comment: @SteveKnau The row's width is not defined. Do I need to define it as 100%?

Comment: @Curious13 that seems like an ugly hack.. I will try

Comment: in my opinion, what you're trying seems more like a hack than what I've suggested. My approach is 1 line of code.

Comment: @Curious13 I need the first column to be aligned with the leftside and the last column to be aligned with the rightside. Does your method still work?

Comment: @Mocha If you only need 3 columns, then that should work fine. You can set the width of `.section` if needed as well.

Comment: @SteveKnau can you please clarify what "That" is in working fine? If I set the width of .section, there will be empty space for my last column. How can I alleviate that?

Comment: I'm referring to the suggestion from @Curious13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bootstrap V4 and you can easily do this by using only `col`:

```css
.section {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.section:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

.section:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col section">
      hello
    </div>
    <div class="col section">
      hello
    </div>
    <div class="col section">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. Can you please explain what the "Issue" is?

Comment: @Mocha with bootstrap V3 you are using float and the element have width defined, so the total is already 100%, adding margin will make it more than 100% so it won't fit in one line. With the last version you have more flexibitly since it rely on flexbox and no width defined